# Datepicker-bootstrap fecha actual

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

Como hago para que el datepicker-bootstrap me ponga la fecha actual por default en el input, he revisado en algunos foros y nada mayormente el que utilizan es jqueri-UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se lo asignas directamente al value del input o a su función de setDate

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

```html
<link srv="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<input class="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con este ejemplo para la fecha actual:

```html
<input type="date" name="cumpleanios" step="1" min="2013-01-01" max="2013-12-31" value="<?php echo date(" Y-m-d ");?>
```

Comment: me refiero a que cuando al cargar el formulario el input del datepicker no me salga en blanco sino con la fecha actual