# Datepicker iniciar con fecha especifica

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

mi datapicker al cargar la pagina me sale en blanco, no logro visualizar la fecha de hoy, trate con algunos metodos pero nada

```
<div class="form-group col-sm">
    <label for="inputPassword4">Fecha:</label>
    <input id="datepicker" size="19">
    <script>
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
            format: 'ddd dd/mmmm/yyyy',
            locale: 'es-es'
        });
        //$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', "0"));
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Datepicker-bootstrap fecha actual](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192529/datepicker-bootstrap-fecha-actual)

Comment: ya lo probe pero en bootstrap4 no va

Answer (score 0):

Puedes setear el datepicker de esta forma:

```
$('#datepicker').val(new Date(2020,6,4)).datepicker('update');
```

Quedando tu código:

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
  format: 'ddd dd/mmmm/yyyy',
  locale: 'es-es'
});
$('#datepicker').val(new Date(2020, 6, 4)).datepicker('update');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="form-group col-sm">
  <label for="inputPassword4">Fecha:</label>
  <input id="datepicker" size="19">
</div>
```

Donde podras poner dentro de `new Date()` la fecha que requieras.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si el resultado que buscas es [*nombre del dia*][*espacio*][*fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy*], si es así, podrías obtenerlo usando `$('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date());` (para obtener la fecha actual) y detallando el formato de fecha como `format: 'D dd/mm/yyyy'` dentro del fatepicker, también he agregando `todayHighlight: true` para que la fecha esté resaltada, algo así:

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
  format: 'D dd/mm/yyyy',
  locale: 'es-es',
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});

$('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="form-group col-sm">
    <label for="datepicker">Fecha:</label>
    <input id="datepicker" size="19">
</div>
```